# Create Dataframes based on array values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that spans over several years.

```
# Import full dataset 
df_all = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dssgPT/Plotting-Good-DSSG/main/desafios/006_Incendios/area_ardida.csv')
# Assign years variable to unique values in years column
years = df_all['year'].unique()
# Print years variable
print(years)

array([1999, 2000, 1997, 1992, 1995, 1998, 1980, 1996, 1982, 1987, 1989,
       1991, 1981, 1983, 1984, 1986, 1988, 1990, 1993, 1994, 1985, 2005,
       2006, 2007, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2008, 2009,
       2013, 2014, 2017, 2019, 2021, 2015, 2018, 2020, 2016])
```

My objective is to create different dataframes for each year, and then do some operations.
I could do it manually as in this example below

```
df_2017 = df_all[df_all['year']==2017]
df_totals_2017 = df_2017.groupby(["concelho", "year"]).sum()
df_totals_2017.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/2022/DATAVIZ/dssg_2017.csv')
```

but I'm wondering if there is a optimal way of doing this.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the required outcome simply that a CSV is generated for each year? Does it necessarily need to be stuffed into a variable named with the specific year value?

Comment: For the specific case yes

Comment: Yes... to which of my two questions...?

Comment: Is your dataframe save on some sort of cloud service or anything correlated, or is it locally saved i am asking this because utilizing pandas for such tasks isnt exactly recommended

Comment: Whenever you see yourself needing to dynamically create variable names, that should set off a red flag.  There are plenty of ways to operate on individual years within a single dataframe.  If the requirement is yearly outputs, perhaps you can save the splitting until the output stage.

Comment: @esqew yes the outcome should be a CSV generated for each year, and returning the sum of the column "sum" for each ```concelho```

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 the original dataset  is saved on GitHub. The resulting csv will be saved locally. The example posted here is from my attempts with Google Colab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to do it, not sure if it is most efficient but hey it will do the job

```
for i in years:
    grouped_df = df_all[df_all.eq(i)].groupby(["concelho"]).sum()
    #Little redundant to groupby year
    grouped_df.to_csv(f'/content/drive/MyDrive/2022/DATAVIZ/dssg_{i}.csv')
```

Comment: If you are looking for speed, another approach would to transform the dataframes into numpy momentarily and then, reindex the indexes of the df.

Comment: @INGIOR1AMOR1 I actually tried it but it returns empty csv files for each year.

Comment: @INGIOR1AMOR1 this does work 
grouped_df = df_all[df_all.year.eq(i)].groupby(["concelho"]).sum()

Comment: oh, hahaha okay then

Answer (score 2):

Taking your code and restructuring it slightly to loop over all the `year`s and construct a dictionary of split dataframes

```
many_dfs = {y: df_all[df_all['year']==y] for y in df_all['year'].unique()}
```

On further exploration of this dictionary

```
>>> many_dfs.keys()
dict_keys([1999, 2000, 1997, 1992, 1995, 1998, 1980, 1996, 1982, 1987, 1989, 1991, 1981, 1983, 1984, 1986, 1988, 1990, 1993, 1994, 1985, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2008, 2009, 2013,2014, 2017, 2019, 2021, 2015, 2018, 2020, 2016])

>>> type(many_dfs[2017])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

>>> many_dfs[2017].columns
Index(['Distrito', 'concelho', 'month', 'year', 'sum', 'longitude',
   'latitude'],
  dtype='object')
```